# Get filename of file repaired by chkdsk

Tags: chkdsk

I've got this error when running `chkdsk /f`:

```
D:\>chkdsk /f
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Cannot lock current drive.

Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another
process.  Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first.
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID.
Would you like to force a dismount on this volume? (Y/N) Y
Volume dismounted.  All opened handles to this volume are now invalid.
Volume label is DATA.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
Correcting total allocated size in attribute record (80, "")
of file 1000000027459.
  411392 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  567 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  939 reparse records processed.
  444476 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
  939 reparse records processed.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
  16543 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows has made corrections to the file system.
No further action is required.

 937692463 KB total disk space.
 759996540 KB in 146798 files.
     63424 KB in 16544 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    506111 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 177126388 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 234423115 total allocation units on disk.
  44281597 allocation units available on disk.
```

Would like to know which filename belongs to file 1000000027459 so I can compare against my backup if file size and checksum match.

On some websites they say that this is a phantom error because the filesystem is still on use or because can happen.

Comment: See this page>>>>>https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=68605

Comment: CHKDSK /V (Verbose) produces the most detailed information. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk

Once done, you would need to interpret the results. Here is a tutorial for interpreting the results. https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/40822-read-chkdsk-log-event-viewer-windows-10-a.html

Remember that CHKSDK does not (cannot) reassemble errors into the original file(s) which is why you need to interpret the results as above.

Comment: There was a desire to add the steps to review the CHKDSK log. That was not practical give the limited text and copious screen shots. However there are lots of articles on how to read the Event Viewer. I trust this helps.

Comment: @John I've already performed the chkdsk. Apparently that file doesn't exist, just check how big the number is. The article on arstechnica recommends the use of Disk Explorer for NTFS, however it won't accept such big number.

Comment: That means that the damaged bits have just been aggregated into a CHDKSK block and the file cannot be identified.

Comment: @John I've modified the OP to add the entire log. Please review and let me know what you think.

Comment: It is not the result of drive damage and it says that nothing was lost / found.  There is nothing to recover.  Have you lost data?  Or are you just wondering at this point?

Comment: I believe it is a file in your system you cannot see unless you are running a recovery application which bypasses all of Windows securities and just reads the disk. Thus the _file record_.

Comment: @John I am wondering at this point, didn't notice any missing file. I just expect the usual `Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required.`

Comment: @vssher what's the file record?

Comment: What happens if you run it again (no repairs or logging - just a check run)?

Comment: @John successive chkdsk's after fixing the error say `Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems. No further action is required.`. Also didn't experience any other error.

Comment: So there is really no problem with the filesystem. It appears to have been a strange errors message